# setImage method of UIImageView not working sometimes

Tags: ios, image, show

I have a `UIImageView` to show an image and a button to switch images from disk.

```
- (IBAction)loadNextImage:(id)sender {
if (m_currentPage >= m_pageCount - 1)
{
    return;
}
m_currentPage++;
[self showImage:m_currentPage];

}
```

and the `showImage` method call the setImage method of `UIImageVIew`.
All this works well in simulator. But in my iphone4, for some certain images, it didn't show these images when I click the button to switch to these images. It still shows the last image. BUT When I make the app running in background and then switch it to foreground, the UI shows the image it should be!

I debuged it and the image parameter passed to `setImage` is not `nil`. 
The image is about 200k. Is it too large? Is there anyone knows the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that the filenames match exactly what you are trying to load, i.e. `image1.png` is not the same as `Image1.png` as far as a device is concerned. But this will work in the simulator.

Comment: The image name is no problem. The name is generated by codes and it's a number.